# Xlaunch vs Startx vs Startxwin vs Xterm vs X Display Environment Packages

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, cygwin, xorg

I have downloaded `Cygwin` on my `Windows` machine and `ssh` into an `Unix`-based machine.

What is the difference between `Xlaunch`, `Startx`, `Startxwin`, `Xterm`, and X Display Environment Packages (`GNOME Flashback Desktop Environment, KDE Plasma Desktop Environment, LXDE Desktop Environment, MATE Desktop Environment, Xfce Desktop Environment`)?

I tried reading through http://x.cygwin.com/docs/ug/cygwin-x-ug.pdf, but it is extremely confusing for a person with somewhat knowledge of computers and a desire to learn about them.
Appreciate if you could simplify the differences for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 standard ways to initiate the XWin X Server on cygwin:

```
1) Use the X Server on the Menu.
2) Run startxwin from the shell.
```

The two methods are equivalent.
`startx` is the default method on a Unix/Linux Machine, but it need some adaptation on cygwin, so `startxwin` was created.

Xterm is a terminal. It provides X interface capability to another program typically a command shell and requires the X Server running.

xlaunch: GUI tool for configuring and starting the XWin X server. It is an optional auxiliary tool; you can ignore it.

The X Display Environments provide additional look and feel flavors on top of the X Server capability.